# how likely is it to contract genital HSV1 if you already have oral HSV1?

Tags: herpes

I've encountered several pieces of conflicting information about susceptibility to genital HSV1 for a partner already infected with oral HSV1.

Some sources seem to suggest the risk of genital infection is very low, while others merely note that infection is possible. Is there any hard data on this?

Comment: One of the question in what I just linked is "what is the likelihood if the person contracting it has already been exposed to oral HSV1"